# Как отрисовывать по пикселям в opengl?

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

Использую библиотеку SharpGL в WPF приложении, как можно нарисовать линию с нужными размерами и отступами в пикселях? И как сделать так, чтобы эта линия не растягивалась с изменение размеров окна?

И можно как-то с помощью Perspective делать нужный зум? Например х3 или х0.5

```
private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args) {
    OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

    // Сбрасываем цвета и глубины
    gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);



    gl.LoadIdentity(); // Сбрасываем матрицу

    gl.Translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.5f);
    gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_LINES); 

    gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);


    gl.Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f);


    gl.End();

    gl.Flush();
}

private void OpenGLControl_Resized(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args) {
    OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

    // Сброс матрицы проекции
    gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.LoadIdentity();

    // Рассчитать соотношение сторон окна
    gl.Perspective(45.0f, (float)gl.RenderContextProvider.Width / (float)gl.RenderContextProvider.Height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    // Устанавливаем матрицу представления
    gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Comment: Что такое "линия с нужными отступами"?

Comment: Простите, упустил слово во время редактирования, я имел ввиду "размерами и отступами". В общем, как задавать параметры в пикселях?

Comment: Вы хотите 2D графику на переднем фоне, типа UI, а на заднем фоне 3D ? Можно начать с того, что сам бекбуффер(экран) - это текстура, а текстуры можно попиксельно изменять, накладывать друг на друга. А в вашем коде манипуляции исключительно с 3D графикой.

Comment: Я хочу рисовать исключительно 2D графику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю этот код вам поможет:

```
private double _scale = 1.0;

    private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

        gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.LineWidth(12.0f); // Толщина линии

        gl.PushMatrix(); // Сохранить текущую матрицу
        gl.Scale(_scale, _scale, _scale); // Маштабировать матрицу

        gl.Color(0, 255, 0);
        gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_LINES);
        gl.Vertex(300, 100);
        gl.Vertex(300, 300);
        gl.End();

        gl.PopMatrix(); // загрузить сохраненную матрицу
    }

    private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

        gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.ClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    private void OpenGLControl_OnResized(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        var gl = args.OpenGL;

        gl.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);  //  Создать ортографическую проекцию
        gl.LoadIdentity();
        gl.Ortho(0, OpenGlControl1.ActualWidth, OpenGlControl1.ActualHeight, 0, -10, 10);

        gl.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview); //  Вернуться назад к модельной проекции
    }

    private void OpenGlControl_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            _scale += 0.1;
        }
        else
        {
            _scale -= 0.1;
        }
    }
```

И обычно всегда есть хорошие примеры от тех кто писал библиотеку. Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpgl/tree/master/source/SharpGL/Samples) на примеры с официального репазитория проекта.

UPD: Код xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SharpGLProblem.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sharpGL="clr-namespace:SharpGL.WPF;assembly=SharpGL.WPF"
    Title="Sample" Height="400" Width="600">
<Grid>
    <sharpGL:OpenGLControl 
        MouseWheel="OpenGlControl_OnMouseWheel"
        Name="OpenGlControl1"
        Resized="OpenGLControl_OnResized"
        OpenGLDraw="OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw" 
        OpenGLInitialized="OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized"
        RenderContextType="FBO" />
</Grid>
```

Надеюсь теперь все станет понятно.

Comment: Ничего не отображает на экране

Comment: Спасибо, теперь заработало. У меня ещё один вопрос, когда я меняю размеры окна есть ощутимая задержка где-то в секунду когда размеры рисунка сново нормализуются, этого можно как-то избежать?